# Python Pip Error When Installing Dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, manjaro

I am trying to install the following dependencies:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
click==6.7
Flask==1.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
packaging==16.8
prometheus-client==0.0.19
pyparsing==2.2.0
Werkzeug==0.15.3
```

But no matter which dependency I try to install I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==19.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py", line 45, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip._internal.self_outdated_check import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import ensure_binary
ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_binary' from 'six' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py)
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Not sure, but name of script `self_outdated_check.py` makes me think that one of packages is outdated.

Comment: Can you please upgrade pip and reinstall all ?

Comment: @Ananth.P, if I run `sudo pip install --upgrade pip ` I get the same error as above. Is my python install corrupted now?

Comment: @M.K Are you getting the same error after upgraded the pip ? or upgrading a pip its a problem ?

Comment: Well it's not upgrading because as soon as I run that command it throws the error

Comment: Better, do uninstall the pip , and reinstall the pip again

Comment: Just did that and I think it has corrupted my whole python installation - hate Python.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but on Windows with:

`pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\***~1\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`

Everything installs correctly. So I would say that the issue is not with the package stack.

Comment: @M.K. Dont think the way, keep try .better reboot the system and check,if suppose its not helped you ,reinstall python and your dependencies etc..

Comment: OK, I've found the problem. It's the way my Linux distro has decided to handle python packages. It's their view that pip breaks environments between version upgrades of the distro. So the way they have configured python to run is different and to install packages they have their own custom tool.

Comment: Did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer here specifically for people that use Manjaro Linux (where the use of `pip` is not recommended as it can break one's environment if not used correctly). It can also result in subsequent distro updates to not happen seamlessly and may result in manual intervention required.

The solution to undo the damage to the environment is to use:

```
sudo pacman -Syu python-pkgname --overwrite='*'
```

where `pkgname` is the name of the python dependency you want to install. After this is done, the environment should be fixed and subsequently it will not be required to apply the `--overwrite` option.

This whole Python 2 and Python 3 and the resulting pip2 and pip3 tools separation is insane.

Comment: simple way to circumvent: don't try to mess with system python and instead install a python distribution (I use miniconda) in your home directory